# Array won't split (using splice(0))

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, perlin-noise

I am attempting something like a perlin noise map, but my array won't duplicate! As a result the array value exceeds the expected value (>2).

Array "**map**" consist of only 1's and 0's.

A copy of **map** is made (called **cache**) and values from the array "**cache**" are added to the array "**map**".

Some values of **cache** are added to **map** multiple times.

The problem is any change made to "**map**" *appears* to be duplicated on "**cache**", very frustrating. I'm not familiar enough with javascript to know what I did wrong.

relivant code:

```
    var map = terrainSeed(); //returns an array of 1's & 0's (random)
    map = terrainGen(map, map, 2, 2);   

    function terrainGen(mapNew, mapOld, x, y)          
    {            
        var cache = mapOld.slice(0);
        var asdf = 0;

        //if(x >=2) if(y >=2)
        for(var i = 0; i < cache.length; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < cache[i].length; j++)
            {
                var save = mapNew[i][j];
                asdf = cache[(Math.floor(i/x))][(Math.floor(j/y))];
                mapNew[i][j] += asdf;    

                if(mapNew[i][j]>2) alert(save + " + " + asdf + " = " + mapNew[i][j] + " (" + i + ", " + j + ")");                        
            }
         }
        return mapNew;
    }
```

Comment: slice(0) is redundant         var cache = mapOld.slice(0);
is the same as saying         var cache = mapOld;

Comment: `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array

Comment: When you define a variable, you're not "caching", you're simply creating a reference.  A variable doesn't equal a new value.  A variable traces back the the original data.

Comment: @elijuh so why do changes to cache effect mapNew?

Comment: @Xero it's not suppose to be a reference, it's suppose to be an "independent" duplicate array. if slice is not the right function what is?

Comment: @wateriswet redundancy isn't my issue, do you know why slice is not creating an independent duplicate?

Comment: @ApolloCreed that's because the slice only shallow copies the reference, supposing the elment in mapOld and mapNew is and object/array but not primary type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `slice` is doing shallow copy, what you need is a deep copy. so either use some third-party lib like JQuery, Lo-Dash or implement it by your self.

**Using JQuery**

```
var cache = $.extend(true, [], mapOld);
```

**Using Lo-Dash**

```
var cache = _.cloneDeep(mapOld);
```

Comment: thanks! out of curiosity when would you actually use a shallow copy and not just act on the array itself?

Comment: when copy an array with only primitive type elements

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [elaijuh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2633697/elaijuh)'s answer, using pure JavaScript, you'd need to loop through the mapOld array values to create a new array...  Here is how it would:

```
var cache = new Array;
for (var i=0;i<mapOld.length;i++) {
  cache[i] = mapOld[i];
}
```

You're simply pulling the values from `mapOld` and putting them into `cache`...  This is probably how libraries implement it, accept in a function...  Here is how you'd make a function:

```
clone = function(input){
  if (input instanceof Array) {
    var output = new Array;
    for (var i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
      output[i] = input[i];
    }
    return output;
  }
}

// Then using...
cache = clone(mapOld);
```

Here is an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/takcdb6w/3/)

Comment: that only works for array with primitive type elements. operator `=` is also assigning reference for object. so this might not work for @ApolloCreed's requirement.

Comment: @elaijuh He said his array contains 1's and 0's.

Comment: @elaijuh funny enough, "var cache = new Array; var cache = mapOld;" appears to work despite being an array of arrays. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ (100% of my knowledge of primitive vs complex variables comes from this article: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Variables_and_Types#Primitive_Types)

Comment: @Xero you're right, once I started implementing recursive functions it became very clear it does not work properly :-/ elaijuh's answer is the best!

Comment: @Xero he is operating on 2d array that what i guess